# Unable to write Raster using Gdal in Python. Error:dict' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to create a raster file after filling NO DATA with some value using gdal in Python.

I have a function that gets me the raster array.

```
def raster2array(rasterfn):
try:
    bndNum_Val_Dic={}
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    for bandNum in range(raster.RasterCount):
        bandNum += 1
        band=raster.GetRasterBand(bandNum)
        bandVal=band.ReadAsArray()
        bndNum_Val_Dic[bandNum]=bandVal
    raster=None
    return bndNum_Val_Dic
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Using the array generated from from this function I am trying to write my raster which throws an error at "outband.WriteArray(array)" that dict' object has no attribute 'shape'.

```
import numpy as np
import gdal
from osgeo import osr
rasterfn ="MAH_20.tif"
newRasterfn ="MAH_FND.tif"
array= raster2array(rasterfn)
newValue = 100
Driver= 'GTiff'
bandNumber=1
raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
cols = raster.RasterXSize
rows = raster.RasterYSize
bandCount=raster.RasterCount
rasterDataType=raster.GetRasterBand(bandNumber).DataType
global Flag
if(Flag):
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(Driver)
    global outRaster
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, bandCount, rasterDataType)
    Flag=False

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(bandNumber)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(bandNumber)
outband.WriteArray(array)
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outRaster.GetRasterBand(bandNumber).SetNoDataValue(newValue)
raster=None
if(bandNumber==bandCount):
    outRaster=None
    outband=None
    raster=None
```

I am using python 3.5 and GDAL 3.0.2. Is there any way to fix this? 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are trying two write a dictionary while `GDAL` expects a Numpy array. It's not completely clear which data you are trying to write, but changing your write statement to something as shown below should at least get rid of the error message. But make sure you write the correct band.

```
outband.WriteArray(array[bandNumber])
```